# /etc/init.d/rc missing in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, init.d

I would need to adapt some scripts from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and /etc/init.d/rc is missing in Ubuntu 18.04.

This path was moved to a different one or everything was migrated to systemd? If it was moved, can you please specify its location in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2):

`systemd` switched off of scripts in `/etc/init.d/`, and stopped using `/etc/rc.local`.  A similar question was asked on Unix & Linux and the [answers provide great explanations with references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471824/what-is-the-correct-substitute-for-rc-local-in-systemd-instead-of-re-creating-rc).

Your immediate thought may be that init scripts are really complicated, and you're unsure how to convert what you have to `systemd`.  Really, setting things up with `systemd` is a lot easier than with the complicated bash scripts found in `/etc/init.d/`.  There is even a converter, `systemd-sysv-generator`, that you can use instead.

Some have chosen to use `systemd` to run the existing scripts, without modification.  In this example, `/etc/rc.local` is run, but you can select which script to run.

`/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service`

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local
TimeoutSec=0
#StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```bsh
systemctl start rc-local # Test it works.
systemctl enable rc-local # Enable run at boot/as configured
```